# JavaScript - Dynamically creating Select Option values

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamic, innerhtml, createelement

Trying to create a form where a user can enter a variable number of expenses. There are four fields, an expense description, the state the expense took place in, an expense type and a cost. The user clicks an "Add New Expense" button to add another section of these fields to the page. I've got three of the four fields working - Description (input type text), Type (radio buttons) and cost (text). But the state is a dropdown, that pulls the states from a database. The db connection is fine, and PHP creates a string of  tags with relevent values.

Below is the JavaScript, and I should note that it works just fine on Firefox, but not IE, which just seems to create a blank select field with nothing in its dropdown.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var instance = 1;

function newExpense(element) {
    instance++;

    var state = document.createElement("SELECT");
    var stateLabel = document.createElement("LABEL");

    state.id = "expensestate" + instance;
    state.name = "expnsestate" + instance;
    state.innerHTML = "<?php echo $stateDropDown ?>";

    stateLabel.setAttribute("for", state.id);
    stateLabel.innerHTML = "State: ";

    document.getElementById("expenses").appendChild(stateLabel);
    document.getElementById("expenses").appendChild(state);
}
</script>
```

Like I said, this seems to work perfectly in Firefox. It generates valid HTML and the dropdown works as expected. But in IE it creates the select form field, but with an empty dropdown. Any clues to what I may be missing would be most appreciated!

Edit - Paired down the code to the essentials. Thanks for the tip! :)

Comment: How much of that code is relevant to your question?

Comment: All of it is used in the generation of the form elements, though I suspect just the sections with state/stateLabel are specific to the question. I can pair it down to just that, if it'd be helpful. I include the rest, to show what IS working.

Comment: Yes, your questions will always get more attention if you've reduced it to the smallest example that fully reproduces the issue. We don't care what IS working if it has no impact on the part that ISN'T working.

Comment: Try using `var opt = state.appendChild(document.createElement("option")); opt.value = "the value"; opt.text = "the text";` I don't think IE likes `.innerHTML` on `select` elements.

Comment: ...you could also try: `state.appendChild(new Option("the text", "the value"));`

Comment: As you're going to the trouble of generating the Options for the Select in PHP, why not just generate the whole element? `<select>` and all?

Comment: "you could also try: state.appendChild(new Option("the text", "the value")); "
This did the trick! Thanks much for the answer. Had each state as an element in an array and ran it through a loop calling that line with the appropriate elements. Works like a charm. Thanks again.